# How to save data in ng-grid?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have seen the post "How can I update my server with changed data from ng-grid?" but i think it's not feasible for my situation. I have multiple ng-grid (could be more than 15 inside of multiple accordion) in same controller. Keeping track of all those individual cells of an individual ng-grid does not seem to be sensible. Is there a way to extract whole data of one ng-grid rather than keeping track of individual cells??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to **ngGridEventData** event, so when the grid data source is changed this event is fired letting you know that data was successfully modified.

Example:

html:

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <button ng-click="addPerson1()">Add PersonA</button>
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptionsA"></div>
          <button ng-click="addPerson2()">Add PersonB</button>
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptionsB"></div>     
    </div>
```

js:

```
   app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.gridOptionsList=[];
        $scope.myDataA = [
                 {name: "Moroni", age:29},
                         {name: "Tiancum", age: 35},
                             {name: "Jacob", age: 15},
                             {name: "Nephi", age: 75},
                             {name: "Enos", age: 7}
                             ];
            $scope.myDataB = [
                 {name:"Moroni",age:29},
                         {name:"Tiancum",age:35},
                             {name:"Jacob",age:15},
                             {name:"Nephi",age:75},
                             {name:"Enos",age:7}
                             ];

        $scope.gridOptionsA = { 
            data: 'myDataA'
            };

          $scope.gridOptionsB = { 
            data: 'myDataB'
            };

            $scope.gridOptionsList=[$scope.gridOptionsA,$scope.gridOptionsB];

            $scope.addPerson1=function(){
              $scope.myDataA.push({name: "Alex", age:30});

            }
             $scope.addPerson2=function(){
              $scope.myDataB.push({name: "Ben", age:40});
            }

        $scope.$on('ngGridEventData', function (event,gridId) {
          var filteredGrid=$scope.gridOptionsList.filter(function(grid){
            return grid.gridId==gridId;
          })
             $scope.filteredGrid=filteredGrid[0];
             //grid data
             $scope.filteredGridData=$scope.filteredGrid.ngGrid.data;
        });
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/aFZ6YJ0cqHdRZNdasfJ6?p=preview

Comment: I actually require to know how to save data from each ng-grid. How do i extract data from ng-grid as whole, i.e. one ng-grid {whole data} second ng-grid {whole data} rather than keeping track of individual cell of each ng-grid?

Comment: by using the gridId in the event listener you can get the specific grid, I updated my answer with live example

Comment: okay now once i get the grid Id how do i extract the data that is displayed by that grid.

Comment: you can use array of grids and by grid id find the specific grid, I updated my answer + live example

Comment: Thank You so much for your help. Even though you did answer my question but still it seems ng-grid doesn't seem to quite work with multiple grids. For e.g. suppose there is one master ng-grid and all the selected items from this master ng-grid fills up two child ng-grid. And both the child ng-grid has editable columns of it's own. So now when i put any value in those editable columns (in child ng-grid) the data gets mixed up between the grids. Checkout out the plunker link below. May be i am not implementing correctly i am not sure. Any suggestions would be hightly appreciated.

Comment: where is the plunker ?

Comment: the data gets mixed up between the grids because they have the same data source (dt),I gave enother data source for each grid, example :http://plnkr.co/edit/wYlgpYD9oD3ek19YM0Gj?p=preview

Comment: Yup it does work with different source. But what i am trying to achieve is by having this main grid which will contain all the data, and when user selects certain rows he should see those selected rows in child grids and then perform task on those child grids. So there is no other way to do this other than having separate sources for each child grid? Is there any other work around?

Comment: when selecting certain rows you can always clone the array and this way you decouple the arrays,
use : var arr2 = arr1.slice(0); for cloning the array.

Comment: Thank You for all the help and suggestions that too with demo code. Cloning the array performs shallow copy while i think i need deep copy. May be I need to dig more on this Angularjs. And Now instead of grid inside of accordion I am looking for something like nested grids. Unfortunately ng-grid doesn't provide this features. May be i will look for some other options.